# Specifying HDInsight 3.2 Instance Size via powershell

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

According to new HDInsight [pricing schema](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/) and [release notes](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/hdinsight-release-notes/), you can now specify the size of the instance (A3-A9 and D3-D14). I, however, couldn't find a way of how to specify the instance size when creating a new cluster via powershell New-AzureHDInsightCluster command. I did find that see that now it accepts [-DataNodeVMSize](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/commit/26f8b60bcc8d55240fedb66c522100bba8aaf22b), however it doesn't understand keywords like "A7", and when specifying "Extra Large" it creates a standard A3 cluster. Any suggestions whether it's actually possible to specify instance size at the moment?

The "available" VM sizes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx

Here is the script I am running:

> $VmSize = "Small";

```
New-AzureHDInsightCluster -Name $clusterName `
              -ClusterType Hadoop `
              -Version $MyClusterVersion `
              -Location $MyClusterLocation `
              -ClusterSizeInNodes $NumClusterNodes `
              -Credential $HdInsightCreds `
              -DefaultStorageAccountName $DefaultStorageAccountFqdn `
              -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
              -DefaultStorageContainerName $hadoopContainer' `
              -DataNodeVMSize $VmSize `
              -HeadNodeVMSize $HeadNodeVmSize
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already mention, as for now, *HDInsight* clusters only support nodes within `A3-A9` and `D3-D14`.

The link you provided shows pretty clear the codes asociated to each node type and size. The code `Small` belongs to the instance type `A1\Small`, which is not supported by *HDInsight*. Thus, it might consider the use of the smallest available instance, which is, in this case, `A3\Large`.

You should try specifying other instances that fall under the ranges supported by the *HDInsight* cluster. I can see you have already tried with `extra large`. You might want to try typing the code according to the code index available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx) (under *Sizes for Web and Worker Role Instances*), for example.

```
A3: Large
A4: Extralarge
```

Comment: this blog post may provide additional information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2015/05/11/understanding-hdinsight-custom-node-vm-sizes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use the values from the [Sizes for Web and Worker Role Instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx) section like `"ExtraLarge"` (no space), `"A6"` or `"Standard_D3"`?

It looks like the node sizes that are currently supported are listed at: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/ but you have to use the id's from the **Sizes for Web and Worker Role Instances** section, *not* the **Sizes for Virtual Machines** section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx.

Comment: Even when specifying "Small", it still creates a A3 (4 cores, 7 GB memory)

Comment: Are you using [0.8.14](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v0.8.14-February2015)?  Can you share your code?  If you are doing any pipelining after New-AzureHDInsightConfig it might be [dropping the setting](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/179).  If you save the config in `$config`, you can reset it by doing `$config.DataNodeVMSize = "Small"` before you call `New-AzureHDInsightCluster`.  Also, you can check the config object by piping to `format-custom` instead of `New-AzureHDInsightCluster`. (like: `$config | format-custom`)

Comment: Yes, I am using 0.8.14. I've added the code I am using to original question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting back an exception like `Unable to complete the cluster create operation. Operation failed with code '400'. Cluster left behind state: 'Error'. Message: 'UnsupportedNodeSizeSpecified'.`?  That would indicate that you are selecting an unsupported node size.  It looks like the node types that are currently supported are listed at: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/ I just ran tests with "ExtraLarge", "A6" and "Standard_D3" and all seemed to work.

Comment: Also there is what appears to be an errant `'` character in your code above that may be causing a problem if it's actually in the code that you are testing with. (After $hadoopContainer)

Comment: For head node size, "extralarge" had worked and A4 head node was created, but for data node size, values "extra large", "extralarge", "a4", "A4" was ignored and A3 data node was created. Probably simply need to wait for an official support of the "-DataNodeVMSize" parameter. Thank you guys for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell command New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster to create cluster.
and can provide value for -HeadNodeSize, -WorkerNodeSize.
Follow link for VmSizes https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-sizes-specs/.

For D14 machine you can provide size as Standard_D14, mentioned in Size column in above article.